# relational access in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, frameworks

I want to join two tables in Yii 2 that have relation each other.
For example I have a model named `Digital` and model named `Tablet` that relation Digital model with a foreign key `sup_id`.

So I wanna access and show all of these two tables entities in `ListView`.
But when I use join tag it just access model that call in `Model::find()` !!!!
But I want all of them :(
It shows

```
Getting unknown property: app\models\Digital::sim_num
```

for example.
However I defined relations in their model

Here is my action in SiteController

```
public function actionPagination_product2(){
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([

 'query' => Digital::find()->select("Digital.*")->leftJoin('Tablet','Tablet.sup_id= Digital.id'),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 20,
    ],
]);


   return $this->render('pagination_pro2', [
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   ]);
}
```

And in views/site/pagination_pro2 I have

```
   use yii\widgets\ListView;
   echo ListView::widget([
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
      'itemView' => '_page1',
   ]);
```

And in views/site/_page1 I have

```
<?php
   use yii\helpers\Html;
   use yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier;
?>
<div class = "user">

   <?= $model->sim_num?>

</div>
```

Where is the problem ?:((

Answer (score 1):

Problem is of object when you query with

```
Digital::find()
```

You will get all the property of digital model only

If you want to get the property of another model you could set the another public variable with the same name in digital model

or you could use `(yii/app/Query)::find()` to query your data you will get it as an array

or in query you could diretly get `->asArray()` in query itself and then you 
can use Arraydataprovider to show the data

```
public function actionPagination_product2(){
$data = (new yii/app/Query)::find()->from('digital')->leftJoin('Tablet','Tablet.sup_id= Digital.id')->asArray()->all();
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $data,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 20,
    ],
]);


   return $this->render('pagination_pro2', [
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   ]);
```

and in list view u can use it as

```
 <?= (isset($model["sim_num"] && !empty($model["sim_num"]))?$model["sim_num"]:""?>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ;)
that has same problem that just can showing "Digital" entites and when i want to show "Tablet" entities show message : "undefined index sim_num".

Comment: can u try out my edited answer and check if you are getting any data also you can print $data to check what it is getting as response

Comment: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) and when i use !=null expression show undefined index sim_num error

Comment: can u check the $data does it gives you sim_num as index

Comment: i use print_r and to see what return.just returns digital attributes

Comment: can u try the answer i changed or check if responding data related to digital is present or not in table

Comment: it seems join in query not working . because it just returns digital rows.
yes in table digital peresent.

Comment: do  you have instagram or telegram account to ask my questions faster?

Answer (score 0):

It would be good, if you define relation in your `Digital` model like

```
public function getTablet()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Tablet::class, ['id' => 'sup_id']);
}
```

You don't have to join it in `query` passed to `dataProvider` if you don't use it in query. To access it in view file, simply use:

```
$model->tablet->sim_num;
```

Comment: tnx for your reply ;)

i had defined that relation .

Trying to get property of non-object when using:

$model->tablet->sim_num;

Comment: Your foreign key in DB is required?

Comment: yes i wanna trace by foreign key and show data from multiple tables